# Label content bound to a viewmodel property is not updated during RunWorkerCompleted event of the background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I looked at a couple of threads on the UI update using background workers in the view model, and made code changes as necessary, unfortunately I cant get it to work.

I am trying to update my label content which is bound to a property which implements INotifyPropertyChanged in the view model. The report is created, but The updated label content shows up only on reopening the MyWindow from the Main WindowViewModel.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        

        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, 
            NotificationMessageReceived);

        Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
    }

    private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
    {      
        if (msg.Notification == "ShowMyWindow")
        {
            MyWindow ReportWind = new MyWindow();
            ReportWind.DataContext = msg.Sender;
            MyWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel
{      
    //Fields 
    public static string statusProp = string.Empty;
    BackgroundWorker _BWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    //Properties

    public string LblStatusContent
    {
        get
        {
            return statusProp;
        }
        set
        {
            statusProp = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("LblStatusContent");
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand GoCmd { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel(IDialogService dService)
    {
        _dialogService = dService;
        GoCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Go(_dialogService), () => true);
    }

    private void Go(IDialogService dService)
    {
        //dialogservice to show a savedialogbox
        //do something.

        //start my thread to save a pdf refort
        _BWorker = new BackgroundWorker()
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };


        _BWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        _BWorker.ProgressChanged += new      
            ProgressChangedEventHandler(WorkerProgress);
        _BWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new 
        RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);

        if (_BWorker.IsBusy !=true)
        { 
            _BWorker.RunWorkerAsync();                        
        }
    }

    private void WorkerProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.UserState != null && e.UserState.ToString() != "")
            {
                // LblStatusContent =   
                //((ReportWindow.ReportProgressArg)e.UserState).smsg;
                //BatchCompareProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            ErrorLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                this.LblStatusContent = "Cancelled";
            }
            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                LblStatusContent = "Failed to create report";
                OnPropertyChanged(LblStatusContent);
                LblStatusVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    (Action)delegate()
                        {
                            this.LblStatusContent = "Report created successfully";
                            OnPropertyChanged(LblStatusContent);
                            LblStatusVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                        });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            ErrorLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StartReport();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            ErrorLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.ToString());
        }
        finally { }
    }
}
```

**MyWindow.xaml**

```
<Label Name="lblStatus" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
       Content="{Binding LblStatusContent}" 
       Visibility="{Binding LblStatusVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}" 
       Margin="0,80,12,203" Height="36" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="450" />
```

Comment: I have INotifyPropertyChanged . I also added the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to my XAML in my previous test. It did not work. I will add that piece back again and retest as i made some code changes later.

Comment: I used snoop, the content property of the label shows that it is bound to the correct property, but does not appear on the UI.

Comment: @Mikko, yes MVVM Light, WPF. I tried the Dispatcher helper. did not work. I intialized it in the OnStartup() in App.xaml.cs . and updated the code DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI.

Comment: The DoWork already works, I want the runworkecompleted code to update the UI element, Indicating the report is created successfully.

Comment: @Mikko, this did not work.I want the label t be updated after the report is created.

Comment: Updated my answer with working example.

Comment: If its still not working put example in github and provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this little example helps you figure it out?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="80"
        Width="140">

    <Window.DataContext>
      <viewModel:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Label Content="{Binding Property}" />
</Window>
```

---

```
namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        readonly BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        private string _property;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            _worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    int iterations = 0;
                    Property = "Starting...";
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); 

                    while (iterations < 5)
                    {
                        _worker.ReportProgress(iterations * 25);
                        iterations++;
                        Thread.Sleep(350);
                    }
                };

            _worker.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => 
                Property = string.Format("Working...{0}%", args.ProgressPercentage);

            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => 
                {
                    Property = "Done!";
                };

            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        public string Property
        {
            get { return _property; }
            set { _property = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not get this to work after numerous trials. Can anyone guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I missed subscribing to the INotifyPropertychanged at the class declaration,even though I had implemented the Onpropertychanged correctly. 
To update the property while the window was still open after the background process was completed all I had to do was this : 
**public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged.**